# Designing validation classes

Tags: java, design, data, validation

This is a follow-up of [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/315937/data-validation-separated-class-or-not). I decided to implement what the accepted answer suggests, however, I realized I also needed individual public methods for each member the entity to be validated has, so it is not only validated as a whole, but also its members as separate units:

This is what was suggested:

```
public interface Validable {
    public void setValidator(Validator validator);
    public void validate() throws ValidationException;
    public List<String> getMessages();
}

public interface Validator<T> {
    public boolean validate(T e);
    public List<String> getValidationMessages();
}

public class EventValidator implements Validator<Event> {
    public boolean validate(Event e) {
        // validate each member here, as well as the entity as a whole
        return isValid;
    }

    // etc...
}
```

But now I need public methods for each member of the `Event`. The reason is to use each of these methods in the `Event` setters and methods with a similar purpose, like adding items to a list or a dictionary, initializing data, modifying data, etc.

So I would need something like:

```
public class EventValidator implements Validator<Event> {
    // Validates the whole object
    public boolean validate(Event e) {
        // ...
    }

    public boolean validatePlayers() {
        // ...
    }

    public boolean validateCourts() {
        // ...
    }

    public boolean validateMatches() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This first thing I can see I need is to turn that `Event e` parameter in the "main" `validate(Event e)` method into a member variable so the rest of the methods can access them. But this violates the whole point of this design, which was decoupling the entity from the validator.

What would be the most fitting design to cover my needs? I wouldn't care if I had to start from scratch and totally forget about the current design.

Comment: What's stopping you from passing `e` to the other `validateStuff()` methods?

Comment: 1. the fact that I'd end up have 20+ methods with the same parameter `validateX(Event e)` which screams "extract me into a member variable!!" and 2. I can't do that anyway because the interface wouldn't cover that unless I make a class for each validable member, which is a crazy idea.

Comment: Why you don't parametrize with Event all the other methods? Then all of them can be invoked from controller or from main validate method. I guess main *validate* method results is the sum off all others alltogether. Is'n it?

Comment: Yes the sum of *almost* all others is what `validate` return, but I will also need them to be called individually from other classes. What do you mean with parametrize all other methods with Event? If it means the same than what what said in the first comment, I think I answered that in my comment above

Comment: Ok I see why you don't stack validation calls. But interface doesn't need to have 1 method per validation. Only its implementation has them all. Anyways if you are thinking in to have a single class with all the validations possibles, the coupling is going to be hard to avoid

Comment: Given your choice of method names (validateCourts, validateMatches, etc.), it seems as if your individual objects should be validating themselves.  What prevents you from saying something like `public class Player implements Validator<Event>`?

Comment: @RobertHarvey not at all. Those individual object must be validated in the context of the event. For example, that list of players is not null, that it contains more than 1 player or that the number of players it contains is a multiple of the defined number of players per match in the event, etc.....

Comment: Isn't that why you're passing an Event context?

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes of course that's the reason

Comment: Does the validation occur over the *collection* of players, and not the individual players?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, it's over the collection. Although I might also need a validator for the player class, this is trivial, not important and the question does not regard this matter.

Comment: What does `Event e` contain?

Comment: @RobertHarvey a lot of members. If you really want to see... https://github.com/kpagcha/EventScheduler/blob/master/src/data/model/tournament/event/Event.java

Comment: I see Players and Timeslots in there, but not Courts or Matches.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It doesn't matter. I just made them up in the example to simplify what I meant. All you need to know is that "things should be able to be validated", what's so important about what these are?

Comment: So everything you need is in `Event e` then?  You don't need to pull any data from anywhere else to do the validation?

Comment: @RobertHarvey nope, I don't. All I need is the event and the information it contains. It would be a closed scenario for validation.

Comment: And you don't need to add any *outside* behavior to Event e to cause the validation to happen?

Comment: @RobertHarvey that's a very abstract question, but the answer would be no.

Comment: Do you need multiple implementations of the validation, or just one?

Comment: @RobertHarvey for the moment just one but if it's not much of a fuss I would like to have an extensible design.

Comment: YAGNI. That said, it seems as if the design you have in your question is just fine.  I'm not worried at all about the multiple methods that Laiv is worried about... those are all going to be internal to your validator.

Comment: @RobertHarvey As I said, I'm after extensibility. But if you really stand for YAGNI I would be more than happy to consider your suggestion if you can post it as an answer. According to you, what should be my implementation then?

Comment: Eh, it's just a suggestion, not a mandate.  Everything is a tradeoff; there are no absolutes, even though programmers tend to think in terms of absolutes.  If you do need multiple implementations later, it would seem that your `Validator<Event>` interface already provides that, so it would be quite straightforward to add that later.

Comment: The reason you need individual public method is because you need to call them separatelly from the code using the Event? Why is it not enough to call `validate()` and them check for messages?

Comment: @TulainsCórdova basically the whole point of declaring individual validation methods is to avoid repeating code when checking preconditions and then postconditions (the object as a whole, when it's already supposed to be constructed). We could use pretty much the same individual validation "precondition" methods to valiadate the final state (postconditions) as most of them sumed up.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38990/discussion-on-question-by-dabadaba-designing-validation-classes).

Comment: @Yannis you are 4 days late, the conversation has ended, therefore there is no need of purposeless "modding"

Comment: Hm, you are right @dabadaba. The question had a pending "too many comments" flag, but I didn't notice it was days old when I cleared it. Usually we clear flags within 2-3 hours, no idea why this one stuck around for so long.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might help to realize that Validable and Validator are interfaces that relate to the validation of a single entity, and that you are now trying to force the validation of a composite of entities into this design. Your Validator should only validate the event, do not try to use it to validate the rules for creating the event. Make a distinction between *the event* and *the rules for creating the event*.

Once you gain this insight you have many options going forward.

It seems you are modeling a tennis match. In that case, an event should probably be created by some kind of match-maker. (It might suit you to use the builder pattern?) What you are actually wanting to validate is not *the event*, but the steps in the process of *building an event*. The design you have will do a really great job at validating individual entities, but now you need to validate the rules for composing those entities into an event.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative design where multiple "step" validations can be called separatelly:

==> IValidable.java <==

```
import java.util.List;

public interface IValidable {
    public void setValidator(IValidator<Event> validator_);
    public void validate(String stepTag) throws ValidationException, UnknownStepTagException;
    public String getLastValidationMessage();
}
```

==> IValidator.java <==

```
import java.util.List;

public interface IValidator<T> {
    public boolean validate(T e, String stepTag) throws UnknownStepTagException;
    public String getLastValidationMessage();
    public String getLastStepTag();
}
```

==> Event.java <==

```
import java.util.List;

public class Event implements IValidable {

    public static final String VALIDABLE_STEP_PLAYERS="PLAYERS";
    public static final String VALIDABLE_STEP_COURTS="COURTS";
    public static final String VALIDABLE_STEP_MATCHES="MATCHES";

    private IValidator<Event> validator;
    private String lastValidationMessage;

    @Override
    public void setValidator(IValidator<Event> validator_) {
        this.validator = validator_;
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(String stepTag) throws ValidationException, UnknownStepTagException {
        if (!this.validator.validate(this,stepTag)){
            throw new ValidationException("WTF!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getLastValidationMessage() {
        return this.lastValidationMessage;
    }

}
```

==> SimpleEventValidator.java <==

```
public class SimpleEventValidator implements IValidator<Event> {

    private String lastValidationMessage ="";
    private String lastStepTag="";
    @Override
    public boolean validate(Event e, String stepTag) throws UnknownStepTagException {
        // based on the stepTag executed appropiate privateMethod
        // this example always returns false    
        this.lastStepTag=stepTag;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String getLastValidationMessage() {
        return this.lastValidationMessage;
    }

    @Override
    public String getLastStepTag() {
        return this.lastStepTag;
    }

    private boolean validateThis(){
        return false;
    }

    private boolean validateThat(){
        return false;
    }       

}
```

==> UnknownStepTagException.java <==

```
public class UnknownStepTagException extends Exception {

}
```

==> ValidationException.java <==

```
public class ValidationException extends Exception {
    public ValidationException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

==> Test.java <==

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        Event e = new Event();
        IValidator<Event> v = new SimpleEventValidator();
        e.setValidator(v);
        List<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
        // set other thins to e like
        // e.setPlayers(player1,player2,player3)
        // e.setNumberOfMatches(3);
        // etc
        try {
            e.validate(Event.VALIDABLE_STEP_COURTS);
            messages.add(e.getLastValidationMessage());
            e.validate(Event.VALIDABLE_STEP_MATCHES);
            messages.add(e.getLastValidationMessage());
            e.validate(Event.VALIDABLE_STEP_PLAYERS);
            messages.add(e.getLastValidationMessage());
        } catch (ValidationException e1) {
            messages.add(e.getLastValidationMessage());
            System.out.println("Your event doesn't comply with the fedaration regulations for the following reasons: ");
            for (String s:messages){
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        } catch (UnknownStepTagException e2) {
            System.out.println("Unknown validation step "+v.getLastStepTag());
        }
    }
}
```

===============